# Ubuntu won't completely ignore lid closing

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management, lid

TLDR: I've tried changing both logind and upower configuration files to ignore lid closing action and it still keeps detecting it and acting on it.

I'm trying to use an old laptop as a local Plex server and download content via remote qBitTorrent client. This needs the laptop to be continuously running and accessible.

If I closed the lid the laptop went to suspension mode and therefore it was unaccessible by other devices on the network. I googled the way out of that, but it will keep somehow disabling the laptop and sending it into "half-suspended" mode or something like that. If I lift the lid it gets back to working quickly, but nor Plex or qBitTorrent remote UI will be accessible during the lid closed state.

I've tried changing every Lid action to "ignore" on both logind and upower files and still nothing. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 on an old Lenovo netbook.

I did run the "restart" commands for both configuration changes.

The behaviour I want to get is exactly as it works in Windows, the lid goes down and system doesn't even care about it, not even screen dim or anything. Screen going off would be cool, but Idc if it doesn't happen, I just want the laptop to still be accessible in the network with the lid down.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Did you try the `gnome-tweaks` command: **General** → disable **Suspend when laptop lid is closed** ?

Comment: This seems to have worked. I will report back if not so it is kept in the thread but so far it has worked for several minutes without problems.
Thank you :)